# How to go back to the last accessed activity?

Tags: android

```
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
        public void onClick(View v1) {
            Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(setIntent); 
        }
    });
```

I have created a back button in my application and once the user click on the back button, it will go back to the last accessed activity, but when i click back button, it brings me to exit the apps... what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

Just call [`finish`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) in the button:

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v1) 
    {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: OP has to call startActivityForResult() from previous activity. So Activity still appears.

Answer (score 0):

You simply shouldn't implement "back" button yourself. Its a known anti-pattern on android.

But if you still want to achieve this then simply call `finish()` to close your current activity.

Answer (score 0):

1. why try and implement a system button?! it's already there.
2. you can just run the `Activity.onBack()`

Answer (score 0):

U can try like this also....

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent backIntent = new Intent();
        backIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), yourbackactivityclassname.class);
        backIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(backIntent);
        finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use like this.This is working for me.



@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {  
            Intent intent = new Intent(VisitorChat.this,L2STest.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;    
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```